# Use chart.js and Laravel

Tags: laravel, charts

I would need to figure out how to insert some data that I get from a DB into chart.js using Laravel.
The data is about the created_at and an integer value present in a table (I want the created_at on the x-axis and the value on the y-axis).
The data I detect are taken from the DB through this function:

```
public function FirstDev()
{        
   $time = DataFromRasp::where('MAC', 'C4:A5:DF:24:05:7E')->pluck('RSSI', 'created_at');
   return view('backend.auth.user.singleDevice', compact("time"));
}
```

The model is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Seld\PharUtils\Timestamps;

class DataFromRasp extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = ['MAC', 'RSSI'];

}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. You bring data to your Blade files (as usual).
2. You set the JS variables by echoing a non-escaped JSON string.
3. You import ChartJS library.
4. You prepare the canvas.
5. You write the JS code that sets the chart properties (or copy it XD).

`The controller`

```php
public function FirstDev()
{
    // Simulating your data
    $time = [
        ['RSSI' => 33, 'created_at' => '2022-02-20 19:25:43',],
        ['RSSI' => 55, 'created_at' => '2022-02-20 20:25:43',],
        ['RSSI' => 23, 'created_at' => '2022-02-20 21:25:43',],
        ['RSSI' => -5, 'created_at' => '2022-02-20 22:25:43',],
        ['RSSI' => 9, 'created_at' => '2022-02-20 23:25:43',],
        ['RSSI' => 69, 'created_at' => '2022-02-21 00:25:43',],
    ];

    // Saparating informations for x-axis (labels) and y-axis (data)
    $timestamps_x_axis = [];
    $rssi_y_axis = [];
    foreach ($time as  $row) {
        $timestamps_x_axis[] = $row['created_at'];
        $rssi_y_axis[] = $row['RSSI'];
    }

    return view("backend.auth.user.singleDevice")
        ->with('labels', $timestamps_x_axis)
        ->with('data', $rssi_y_axis);
}
```

`backend.auth.user.singleDevice.blade.php`

```js
{{-- Setting JS variables from PHP --}}
<script>
    // DATA FROM PHP TO JAVASCRIPT
    const labels = {!! json_encode($labels) !!};
    const data = {!! json_encode($data) !!};
</script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.7.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>

<script>
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: labels, // <======= Here I set the x-axis
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: data, // <======= Here I set the y-axis
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Results:** [image]

Comment: Ok, but my data is in the $time variable of the function firstDev(), how do I take the data from that variable and put it into the graph?

Comment: @Max in your `firstDev()` method after the query format the output to an array of `RSSI` and a separate array of `created_at`. If you do not figure out how to do that I'll append that to my answer later today.

Comment: Yes I know how to convert to array (I used the toArray() function in the query), but I don't know what part of the graph script to modify

Comment: @max will you ever mark my answer as accepted ?

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to call ->get() or ->first() method.

should be like this

```php
$time = DataFromRasp::where('MAC', 'C4:A5:DF:24:05:7E')->get()
         ->pluck('RSSI', 'created_at');
```

or

```php
$time = DataFromRasp::where('MAC', 'C4:A5:DF:24:05:7E')->first()
         ->pluck('RSSI', 'created_at');
```

Comment: What's next? How do I fit them into the chart?

Comment: The pluck that you used in applied on the collection level! the pluck in the question is used in the query builder.